# In MS access, How to get attribute value from current querying row?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have two tables. They follow the same ID records.
table1:

```
Index, ID,  Name
1,     101, tester1
2,     102, tester2
3,     103, tester3
```

table2:

```
Index, ID,  Score
1,     101, 82
2,     102, 96
3,     103, 90
```

And, now, I want to create a query on the forth column on the table 1 to show the related score. How to do that?

For me, the SQL is looks like:

```
Select b.Score
From table1 AS a, table2 As b
WHERE a.ID = b.ID
AND ... // how to get the ID value from current querying row??
```

Comment: I am sorry that I did not explain well. The requirement is to show the related score on each row.It looks like: "when I click the 1st row and 4th column on the table 1, 82 will be shown. Similarly, if I click the 2nd row 4th column, 96 will be shown." The current query shows the whole table, not the accurate ID related one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display any set of columns from the two joined tables. So your query could be changed as follows:

```
Select a.Index, a.ID, a.Name, b.Score
From table1 AS a, table2 As b
WHERE a.ID = b.ID
```

You can also use this syntax:

```
Select a.Index, a.ID, a.Name, b.Score
From table1 AS a 
join table2 As b on a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: I am sorry that I did not explain well. The requirement is to show the related score on each row.It looks like: "when I click the 1st row and 4th column on the table 1, 82 will be shown. Similarly, if I click the 2nd row 4th column, 96 will be shown." The current query shows the whole table, not the accurate ID related one.

Comment: I changed the query to return table A and the associated score

Comment: Sorry, your solution is incorrect. The element is still showing the whole joined table, not the single value.

Comment: I think MS access can not implement this requirement. Thanks.